# Android Visibility from GONE to VISIBLE doesn't work first time

Tags: java, android, animation, view, visibility

Hello I have a problem with an animation I try to make.

I use this library [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations).

Here is my layout xml code:

```
    <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonDetails"
         style="@style/Button_Details"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDetails"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/LinearLayout_Details">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox_clmn_text"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox_clme_text"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox_clmn_text"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox_clmn_text"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox_clmn_text"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/checkbox_clmn_text"
            android:checked="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And here my java code:

```
// Declare Variables
@ViewById
LinearLayout linearLayoutDetails;

@Click
void buttonDetails() {
    // Checks Linear Layout Visibility
    if (linearLayoutDetails.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        // Sets linearLayoutDetails Visibility to VISIBLE
        linearLayoutDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // Makes Appear Animation
        YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown)
                .duration(700)
                .playOn(linearLayoutDetails);
    } else {
        linearLayoutDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the first time I press the Button the animation is not working, but after that every other time works.

I did some research and i found that the problem is that i have the visibility set to gone and if I set it to invisible it works fine from the first time. Thing is that I dont want the visibility to invisible but to gone because I dont want the Linear Layout to takes up the space when its hidden.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expect, but try to call  requestLayout() on your linearlayout somewhere before doing the animation.

Do you have the code of YoYo ? It would be great to see the real code.

Comment: Yes I have tried the requestLayout() but it didnt work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just solved a couple of minutes ago using a ViewTreeObserver. In the example below, the variable `currentMode` is a view that I want to animate in and out. Its default value is "gone" and I was having the EXACT same issue you were having.

Here's how I solved it:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = currentMode.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if(currentMode.isShown()) {
            YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown).duration(250).playOn(currentMode);
        }
    }
});
currentMode.setVisibility(mShouldShowMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Using the ViewTreeObserver we can watch global changes to the UI and then react. The `View.isShown()` method checks to see if its visible. If so, then I then start the animation. This works great for me.

Then for the exit animation you have to attach a listener to the out animation like this:

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideOutUp).duration(250).withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        currentMode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
}).playOn(currentMode);
```

Answer (score 0):

workaround:

```
boolean firstTIme = true;

(...)

@Click
void buttonDetails() {
    // Checks Linear Layout Visibility
    if (linearLayoutDetails.getVisibility() == View.GONE || firstTIme) {
        firstTIme = false;
        linearLayoutDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown)
                .duration(700)
                .playOn(linearLayoutDetails);
    } else {
        linearLayoutDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but how is this going to help? You just put a boolean check the rest of the code is the same as mines

Comment: You said everything worked right except the first time you run. My boolean check overcomes that: firstTIme will be true on start so the code inside the if statement will be run no matter what after that it goes back to a simple check on visibility

Comment: Ok I see now where the misunderstanding happened.

The problem is not that the code is not firing up. The code always gets executed but the first time that this is happening if the Linear Layout visibility is set to gone the animation is not working (because I think its not getting render because of the gone visibility, if i set visibility to invisible the animation works fine from the first time because the Linear Layout is getting rendered but I don't want that because that way the Linear Layout is taking up space)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YoYo Library then try this.

```
            YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideInDown)
            .duration(400)
            .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        //this will do the trick
                        YoYo.with(Techniques.Landing)
                            .duration(1)
                            .playOn(view);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            })
            .playOn(view);
```

> You can also use this for continuous animation on any view object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and even with accepted answer I couldn't make it to work. So I did this

```
TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(context);
Transition transition = inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.yoyo_transition);
transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
         ...  
        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            do_stuff_with_yoyo();
        }
        ...
    });

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) getRootView(), transition);
yoyo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

yoyo_transition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <changeBounds android:duration="0">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@+id/yoyo_id"></target>
        </targets>
    </changeBounds>

    <fade android:duration="0">
        <targets>
            <target android:targetId="@+id/yoyo_id"></target>
        </targets>
    </fade>

</transitionSet>
```